# Laravel use resource controller method $id parameter as middleware parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-middleware

I am trying to make a middleware to check if the user has the permissions required to view certain pages. Below the code that I currently use to call the middleware. I now pass the name of the role the user needs to have but I also want to pass through the required id that is used when the store method is called.

Is there a way to do this or should I make either a seperate function in this controller or move the route checking middleware to the routes.php? I prefer not to move it because this would mean I have to redifine all the routes that are already defined by my resource controller.

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('permission:Manager',['only' => [
        'show',
    ]]);
}

public function show($id)
{
  //
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access `$request` object in the `handle` method of your middleware to obtain id of the requested page and the user performing the request, e.g.:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $role)
{
    if ( $request->user() && $request->has('id'))
    {
        if ($request->user()->hasRole($request->id, $role)
            return $next($request);
    }        
    return redirect('/403');  // redirect when not allowed
}
```

Please note the `hasRole` method and the `$role` parameter are just placeholder names for your own method and parameter.

Comment: Thanks. For other people who might find this: the 'id' doesn't get recognised but I found out that you can find these with "$request->route()->parameters()". Just replace id with whatever the names are(in my case the name of the resource.)