# Laravel, show only owner's product list throw same Route and multiple Models

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.7

I am trying to display multiple owner's product lists throw the same route.
For example, my route is:

```
http://example.com/store/public/products
```

N.B: I don't want to put `id` in the route.

Now, I have five tables. They are like,

**users table**

```
+----+---------+------+-------+----------+
| id | role_id | name | email | password |
+----+---------+------+-------+----------+
```

**roles table**

```
+----+------+
| id | role |
+----+------+
```

Role and User have `One-to-One` relationship.
For example, I have two types of role. Admin & Manager.
The Admin is allowed to view all the products but the Manager is allowed to view only products that are owned by him. At first, it seems an easy problem.
But my products have a complex relationship with other tables or models.
Like, My store has many areas which are under different managers.

**areas table**

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | area | user_id |
+----+------+---------+
```

And each area has multiple departments.

**departments table**

```
+----+------+---------+
| id | area | area_id |
+----+------+---------+
```

And finally, each product belongs to specific departments.

**products table**

```
+----+---------+---------------+
| id | product | department_id |
+----+---------+---------------+
```

Now what I am trying to say is, My managers aren't allowed to show products which are under other managers, but admin is allowed to show all products.
I have done the relationship methods correctly in the models. For checking the role of a user, I defined a method named `checkRole` in the `User` model. It looks like this,

```
public function checkRole(){
    return $this->role()->pluck('role')->first();
}
```

And in the controller, I checked the role and showed the products according to roles. That is, in the Controller I tried,

```
public function getProducts(Request $request, Product $products){
    $products = $products->newQuery();

    if (Auth::user()->checkRole() == "manager") {
        $products= $products->whereHas('department', 
            function($query){
                $query->whereHas('area', 
                    function($query){
                        $query->where('user_id', Auth::id());
                    });
            })->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->get();
    }

    else{
        $products= $products->orderBy('created_at' , 'desc')->get();
    }

    return $products;
}
```

It does the work, But is there any better way to do this? I mean throw `Middleware` or `Policy`. I tried `Middleware`, but the problem is, this `Route` is valid for every user.

Comment: a little bit of search would give you the right answer. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39118423/laravel-use-resource-controller-method-id-parameter-as-middleware-parameter (mind the comment of the answer too)